# Is it possible to add more routes when I already did resources :posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my routes i have:

```
resources :posts
```

now say I want to create a new action/view, is it possible to add it inside a block like:

```
resources :posts do
  // new routes other than the show/new/create/delete/update that REST gives me.
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep

```
resources :post do
  get :action, :on => :member
  get 'other', :on => :collection
  post :change, :on => :member
  resources :another_model
end
```

note: these are just samples of what you can do and this does assume Rails 3. For more information you should read the Ruby on [Rails Guide: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add them in. For example, if you want to be able to post to "new_action" you would do

```
resources :posts do
  post "new_action"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Rails Guide: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?  Section 2.9 Adding More RESTful Actions describes exactly what you're looking for.  I frequently refer to the other guides there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for a resource **member**

```
resources :posts do
  get :preview, :on => member
end
```

or this for a resource **collection**

```
resources :posts do
  get :active, :on => collection
end
```

When I was starting out with rails I was confused about what **members** and **collections** were. For a `Post` resource a member is an individual post while a collection is the collection of all posts. For example...

```
# url for a member
/posts/5/preview

# url for a collection
/posts/active
```

The rails guide goes into more detail on [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)